# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report in which I'm displaying the encoded text which got retrieved from a `DataSet`, but in the report, it is displaying the html tags.

Is there any way to Decode the text and display it in the crystal report?

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Share your code with people so they can help you much better.

Comment: I've created an SQL function to Decode the text that got saved in the database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my SQL function to decode the encoded text..

```
CREATE FUNCTION FNHTMLDECODE (@REMARKS NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @RESULT     NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @VCCRLF     VARCHAR(2)

    SET @VCCRLF     =   CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

    SELECT @RESULT  =   @REMARKS

    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'&amp;amp;','&')
    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'&AMP;','&')
    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'&amp;#','&#')
    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'&nbsp;',' ')
    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'&lt;','<')
    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'&gt;','>')
    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'&QUOT;','"')
    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'&COPY;','©')
    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'&LAQUO;','«')
    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'&RAQUO;','»')
    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'&FRAC14;','¼')
    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'&FRAC12;','½')
    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'&IQUEST;','¿')
    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'<BR />', CHAR(10)) --   LINE FEED
    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'&#x0D;', CHAR(13))  -- CARRIAGE RETURN

    SELECT @RESULT  =   REPLACE(@RESULT,'<P>',@VCCRLF)

    RETURN @RESULT
END
```